# How to enable user to edit Power Pivot lookup data

Tags: excel, lookup, powerpivot

Coming from the corporate data warehousing solutions world I found Power Pivot to be surprisingly functional tool that could help to bring BI into small bussiness. In order to educate myself in this area I'm doing a small project for a friend who is a building contractor and asked me to help analyse his costs against different projects. The issue is that some data needs to be provided by user and here is where my narrow knowledge of Power Pivot is starting to show up.

My base data is coming from accounting system. I have access to company books via SQL Server connection, I can import Invoices, Clients, Suppliers, Accounts and all other entries. I made all

the connections and can present data in an easy way in a Pivot table which alone impressed my friend a lot. I was impressed myself how easy and straightforward it was compared to some reporting tools like Microstrategy or Business Objects which I use every day.

What is missing in the accounting system is Project information, say Client has 3 houses which my friend is working on, each of them should be treated as a separate project that we want to calculate profit on. Do do that I need some manual input such as assigning Project to Cost invoice add a category (Materials, Services) etc.

Initially I wanted to create a two lookup spreadsheets:

1. Projects where project name, valid from/to, etc. would be entered manually (or imported from CRM application in the future) and Client which would be selected from a dropdown list (ideally sourced directly from the power pivot Client table)

**QUESTION 1: how to add a dropdown list of Clients coming from Power Pivot table?**

2. Invoice relation table which would hold some data from power pivot Cost Invoice table (invoice number,  supplier, date etc.) and then a dropdown list with projects (from the first spreadsheet) and cost type. Tricky part is that I would like invoice list to be refreshed automatically when new invoices are registered but I don't want to loose any data added manually against them!

**QUESTION 2: how to design such spreadsheet to be populating new invoices automatically but maintaining data linked with it? I was thinking PivotTable with some data next to it but it seems like a very volatile solution, say invoices are sorted by invoice number (which is different system or each supplier) and a new one can show up in the middle of the table, then all projects that were manually added after would start pointing to the wrong invoices.**

Last resort for me is to create an MS Access database for storing/updating lookups but then all the mess with creating ODBC connections etc. comes into play and in my opinion it's defeating the idea of neat PowerPivot Excel spreadsheet...

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

in general you can design an excel table that holds manual input data and feed that table into PowerPivot (via linked table).

as for the drop down info based on database data i suggest using power query. this tool lets you connect to various sources, do some data wrangling and then output that data into excel. these outputs can then serve as data range for excel based drop downs.

take a look at Power Query e.g.here: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605 or here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LACjRvxl_2w.

Comment: Nice feature, possibly I could use it to achieve my goal however I'm a bit worried about security, is there a way to hide tables and disable query editing for the user?

Comment: One can disable the loading of a query/table into excel. The queries itself are always visible and editable though. At least up to the current version. Which is still in beta if I am not misinformed.